# Retrieving Facebook friends working only on my device

Tags: android, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk, restfb

I am developing an app where it retrieves the current user facebook friends. My Code is working on my device but when I run it on any other devices, its not displaying any results.

Could you please let me know where I am going wrong.

my code is as follows :

```
public class FaceBook extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener{

        ArrayList<Param> facebook_names = new ArrayList<Param>();
        Param name = null;
        Names_Adapter adapter;
        ListView Names_List;
        SearchView searchView;
        int check_search =1;
        ArrayList<Param>new_names;
        private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
        private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;



        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_face_book);

            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            bar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_titlebar);
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header));
            //bar.setTitle("Main Menu");
            bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);  
            bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
            uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
            if ( myTitleText != null ) {
                myTitleText.setText("Facebook");
            }

            Log.d("COMP", "TEST");


             Names_List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


             ImageButton reload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reload);
             reload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent restart  = new Intent(FaceBook.this, FaceBook.class);
                    startActivity(restart);
                    finish();
                }
            });



        }

              @Override
              public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                  if (requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
                      uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                  }
              }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.face_book, menu);
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!query.isEmpty())
            {

                check_search = 0;
                new_names = new ArrayList<Param>();
                for(int i=0;i<facebook_names.size();i++)
                {
                    if(facebook_names.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(query))
                    {
                        Param new_param = new Param(facebook_names.get(i).getUrl(),facebook_names.get(i).getName(),facebook_names.get(i).getPic());
                        new_names.add(new_param);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                }

                 Names_Adapter adapter = new Names_Adapter(FaceBook.this,R.layout.facebook_names_list,new_names);
                        Names_List.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                check_search=1;
                 adapter = new Names_Adapter(FaceBook.this,R.layout.facebook_names_list,facebook_names);
                    Names_List.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Names_List.setAdapter(adapter);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int itemId = item.getItemId();
            switch (itemId) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                FaceBook.this.finish();
                break;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void makeRequest(Session session)
        {
            String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid,name,pic,profile_url FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
                        "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY first_name";
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
                session = Session.getActiveSession();

                Request request = new Request(session,
                        "/fql",                         
                        params,                         
                        HttpMethod.GET,                 
                        new Request.Callback(){       
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "Result: " + response.toString());

                        try{
                            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                            Log.d("data", jsonObject.toString(0));

                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){


                                JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);
                              name = new Param(friend.optString("profile_url"),friend.optString("name"),friend.optString("pic"));
                                facebook_names.add(name);
                             //   Log.d("uid",friend.getString("uid"));
                              //  Log.d("name", friend.getString("name"));
                                //Log.d("pic_square",friend.getString("pic_square")); 


                                  adapter = new Names_Adapter(FaceBook.this,R.layout.facebook_names_list,facebook_names);
                                    Names_List.setAdapter(adapter);

                                 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(FaceBook.this);
                                searchView.setOnCloseListener(FaceBook.this);

                             Names_List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                        long arg3) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(FaceBook.this,Web_Activity.class);
                                    if(check_search==0)
                                    {
                                    intent.putExtra("WEB",new_names.get(arg2).getUrl());
                                    intent.putExtra("NAME",new_names.get(arg2).getName());
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        intent.putExtra("WEB",facebook_names.get(arg2).getUrl());   
                                        intent.putExtra("NAME",facebook_names.get(arg2).getName());
                                    }
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }                  
                }); 
                Request.executeBatchAsync(request); 
        }

        private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                // Get the user's data.
                makeRequest(session);
            }
        }



        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null &&
                   (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
            }

            uiHelper.onResume();
        }


         private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
                    onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
                }
            };


        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
            uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            uiHelper.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            uiHelper.onDestroy();
        }
    }
```

I also tried using `restFB` to access the user Facebook friends.

```
AccessToken accessToken =  new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(appid,app secret; 
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken.getAccessToken());

User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
```

When I do this,  it gives me an error stating that a valid access token must be used to retrieve user values.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Facebook Developer site, and under the 'Status and Review' for your app, make it **PUBLIC**. You can always remove from Public later after your 'temporary' testing is complete.

or

Another way would be to print out the key hashes from each device that you are testing your app on, and **add these as key hashes** into Settings>Android in the FB developer for your app.

Comment: NeilDa, Thanks for your reply. I did go and make it public. Its still not working. Do you mean to state that I need to update my key hashes everytime I run my app on other devices?

Comment: At least thats what I noticed with key hash. The key hash for my tablet was different to the one on my phone. However, if public is not working then the key hash wouldn't fix it either.